# Modify XML using Python minidom

Tags: python, xml, dom, minidom

Here is a sample XML file:

```
<Project attri1="build">
    <Import Project="blahblah" xmlns="someURI" />
    <Property>
        ...
    </Property>
    <Property>
        ...
    </Property>
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Scripts" />
        <Folder Include="Scripts/1.0" />
        <Folder Include="Scripts/2.0/" />
        ...
    </ItemGroup>
      ... some irrelevant ItemGroup is here
    <ItemGroup>
         <None Include="Scripts/1.0/001.sql" />
         <None Include="Scripts/2.0/002.sql" />
    </ItemGroup>
    ...
</Project>
```

The above XML file is based on the template of Visual Studio's sqlproj file. It is distinguished based on what kind of nodes are inside.

---

My research:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
sql = xml.dom.minidom.parse('file.sqlproj')
itemGroup = sql.getElementsByTagName('ItemGroup')
folderGroup = itemGroup[0] # The first ItemGroup has folders
sqlGroup = itemGroup[2] # The 3rd ItemGroup has sql file list.
```

I want to add `<Folder Include="newpath" />` and `<Folder Include="newsql" />` into appropriate ItemGroup using Python's xml.dom.minidom library, and eventually override the original sqlproj file.

How to do that?

If you suggest other built-in libraries, please give an example, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell enough info on how to distinguish `ItemGroup`s between each other, but I'm assuming it is based on what kind of nodes are inside.

Here's how you can insert new `Folder` tags into the `ItemGroup` of `Folder`s and `None`s. The idea is to find the first `Folder` and `None` tags, get the parent and `appendChild` to it:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

data = """<Project attri1="build">
    <Import Project="blahblah" xmlns="someURI" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Scripts" />
        <Folder Include="Scripts/1.0" />
        <Folder Include="Scripts/2.0/" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup/>
    <ItemGroup>
         <None Include="Scripts/1.0/001.sql" />
         <None Include="Scripts/2.0/002.sql" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>"""

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(data)

new_folder = dom.createElement('Folder')
new_folder.setAttribute('Include', 'newpath')

folder = dom.getElementsByTagName('Folder')[0]
folder.parentNode.appendChild(new_folder)

new_script = dom.createElement('Folder')
new_script.setAttribute('Include', 'newsql')

none = dom.getElementsByTagName('None')[0]
none.parentNode.appendChild(new_script)

print dom.toprettyxml()
```

It prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Project attri1="build">
    <Import Project="blahblah" xmlns="someURI"/>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Scripts"/>
        <Folder Include="Scripts/1.0"/>
        <Folder Include="Scripts/2.0/"/>
        <Folder Include="newpath"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup/>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="Scripts/1.0/001.sql"/>
        <None Include="Scripts/2.0/002.sql"/>
        <Folder Include="newsql"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, finding the first child and append to its parent.

Comment: @alecxe , it's not updating the file. It just affecting the local data.